# Module acpi not found

Tags: 12.04, kernel, suspend, acpi

My OS is 12.04, I'm not able to suspend and wake up my PC at given time, or better if I run `sudo rtcwake -m mem -s 120`.

My PC enter suspend mode and the power-on light turns up after 2 minutes, but there are no keyboard I/O, no video card working, the PC seems to be turned off, there is only the power-on light to give me the illusion of a running OS.
Furthermore when I run:

```
sudo ls -l /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/kernel/drivers/acpi
```

I got:

```
 total 100
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  8108 apr 10  2013 acpi_ipmi.ko
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 13908 apr 10  2013 acpi_pad.ko
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root  4096 apr 15  2013 apei
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  5728 apr 10  2013 ec_sys.ko
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 10012 apr 10  2013 pci_slot.ko
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  9696 apr 10  2013 sbshc.ko
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 12156 apr 10  2013 sbs.ko
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 25616 apr 10  2013 video.ko
```

But when I run:

```
sudo modprobe acpi
```

I got:

```
FATAL: Module acpi not found.
```

My PC is a FitPc2 and in its website the BIOS is mentioned to be 'RTC wake-up ACPI availability through OS (S3)'.
When running:

```
dmesg |grep acpi
```

Output is:

```
 [    0.000000] ACPI: LAPIC (acpi_id[0x00] lapic_id[0x00] enabled)  
 [    0.000000] ACPI: LAPIC (acpi_id[0x01] lapic_id[0x01] enabled)  
 [    0.000000] ACPI: LAPIC_NMI (acpi_id[0x00] high edge lint[0x1])  
 [    0.000000] ACPI: LAPIC_NMI (acpi_id[0x01] high edge lint[0x1])  
 [    0.876584] ACPI: Requesting acpi_cpufreq  
 [    0.897585] pata_acpi 0000:00:1f.1: setting latency timer to 64  
 [    3.392784] acpi device:04: registered as cooling_device2  
 [    3.445689] acpi device:05: registered as cooling_device3
```

Any idea please? Do I have to enable ACPI in kernel ? How? I tried to modify grub with `acpi=force` but nothing happens. I read about setting the kernel environment variable `hint.acpi.0.disabled=0` that would enable ACPI but how to pass this parameter? in which file ?